# Azure DevOps Pipeline is not copying or deploying all my projects

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I need some help to create my build pipeline.

[image]

At Build solution step I do a classic build with no MSBuild arguments. But in my solution file I have many projects. One of them is the API and 3 of them are 3 clients applications, one winform, one clickonce and one web client.

When I build localy with Visual Studio from a clean solution during the build Visual Studio properly create all bin folder, release or debug subfolder and publish sub folder for related publishable projects.

When I do the same with the MSBuild from Azure DevOps Pipeline I don't know what happens. The logs seems ok but when I copy then publish my artifact I get only few project.

Here is my YAML

```
#Your build pipeline references an undefined variable named ‘Parameters.solution’. Create or edit the build pipeline for this YAML file, define the variable on the Variables tab. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=865972

#Your build pipeline references the ‘BuildPlatform’ variable, which you’ve selected to be settable at queue time. Create or edit the build pipeline for this YAML file, define the variable on the Variables tab, and then select the option to make it settable at queue time. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=865971

#Your build pipeline references the ‘BuildConfiguration’ variable, which you’ve selected to be settable at queue time. Create or edit the build pipeline for this YAML file, define the variable on the Variables tab, and then select the option to make it settable at queue time. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=865971



steps:

- task: VSBuild@1

  displayName: 'Build solution *****.sln'

  inputs:

    solution: '$(Parameters.solution)'

    platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'

    configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'

#Your build pipeline references the ‘BuildConfiguration’ variable, which you’ve selected to be settable at queue time. Create or edit the build pipeline for this YAML file, define the variable on the Variables tab, and then select the option to make it settable at queue time. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=865971



steps:

- task: CopyFiles@2

  displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'

  inputs:

    SourceFolder: '$(system.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'

    Contents: '**\bin\$(BuildConfiguration)\**'

    TargetFolder: '$(build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'



#Your build pipeline references an undefined variable named ‘Parameters.ArtifactName’. Create or edit the build pipeline for this YAML file, define the variable on the Variables tab. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=865972



steps:

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1

  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'

  inputs:

    PathtoPublish: '$(build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'

    ArtifactName: '$(Parameters.ArtifactName)'

  condition: succeededOrFailed()
```

Comment: Have you checked the Output folders of your projects? It may be that they use custom path for those build configurations

Comment: Don't you think I checked that already? Yes I did. I just double checked now and... Oh... it is that. I feel so stupid now.

Comment: It may depends on what is your projects look like, maybe you need to add arguments for them. Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38087636/building-project-in-vsts-doesnt-build-all-projects-in-solution) solution.

Comment: @Bastien Vandamme Looks like your problem is solved . Could you share your solution here ? This can help users with the same issue and we could archive this thread ,thanks.